# Reference to section where is label

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, cross-referencing

I have these equations with one label:

```
\section{This is super math section}
\begin{eqnarray}
c + d \\
\label{eq:eq2}
a + b
\end{eqnarray}
```

But how to do if I want get the section number where is the equation placed and make reference to this section (from the number)?

```
Equation \eqref{eq:eq2} on page \pageref{eq:eq2} in section \???{eq:eq2} is brilliant!
```

EDIT: using ref to definition environmet.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{yhmath}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}

Definition \ref{def:def1} on page \pageref{def:def1} in section \cref{def:def1} is brilliant!

\section{Definitions}
\begin{defi}\label{def:def1}
This is body of definition.
\end{defi}
\end{document}
```

Giving: Definition 1.1 on page 1 in section Definition 1.1 is brilliant!

Need: Definition 1.1 on page 1 in section 1 is brilliant!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: To make a cross-reference to the *section*, you first need to place a separate `\label` statement immediately following the `\section` statement. E.g., you might write `\section{This is a super math section} \label{sec:supermath}`. Elsewhere in the document, you'd write "as is shown in `Section~\ref{sec:supermath}`, ..." Incidentally, don't use the `eqnarray` environment. Instead, learn to use the `align` environment provided by the `amsmath` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [many packages in CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/topic/label-ref) to manage cross references. Unfortunately some are incompatible or must be loaded in some order. For your question a solution could be `\cref` from the `cleverref` package:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{varioref} % before of hyperref and cleveref
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

Equation 
% \vref{eq:eq2} 
 \eqref{eq:eq2} 
% \vpageref{eq:eq2}
in   \cref{eq:eq2} 
named \nameref{eq:eq2} 
 is brilliant!
 \autoref{eq:eq1} is dull.



\section{This is super math section}
\begin{eqnarray}
\label{eq:eq1}
c + d \\
\label{eq:eq2}
a + b
\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**: For the added problem to the question with a `\newtheorem`, another solution could be the `smartref` package:

[image: MWE2]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}[section]

\usepackage{smartref}
\addtoreflist{section}

\begin{document}

Definition \ref{def:def1}
on page \pageref{def:def1} 
in section \sectionref{def:def1} is brilliant!

\section{Definitions}
\begin{defi}\label{def:def1}
This is body of definition.
\end{defi}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution is great but if I use \cref to definition:
\begin{defi}\label{def:grammer}Bla bla\end{defi}, it gives me definition instead of section number.

Comment: It is difficult to give a solution if you do not know the problem. A `defi` environment? That is not defined in the standard article class, for example. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Editted original ask.

Comment: Smartref gives right section number but it is not clickable.

Comment: Load also the `hyperref` package and then change `\sectionref{def:def1}` by `\hyperref[def:def1]{\sectionref{def:def1}}`